# Magento - include/require php file within phtml template file

Tags: php, magento, include

In one of my magento template phtml files I am trying to include a seperate php file.
When I include it I get nothing outputted and when i use require instead I get the following error

```
Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'http://www.site.co.uk/dir/test.php'
(include_path='/home/usr/public_html/app/code/local:/home/usr/public_html/app/code/community:/home/usr/public_html/app/code/core:/home/usr/public_html/lib:.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/usr/public_html/app/design/frontend/theme/edits/template/review/product/view/list.phtml on line 30
```

The first line of the error shows the correct url path and when i go to it directly it works - it just doesn't like being included/required from the phtml template page.

I've tried the following in the phtml file (using magento's BaseURL, absolute path and the relative path):

```
<?php 
$root = Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB);
require/include ($root.'dir/test.php');
?>

<?php 
require/include ('http://www.site.co.uk/dir/test.php');
?>

<?php 
require/include ('../../../../../../../../../dir/test.php');
?>
```

Comment: I really can not think of any reason why you would do that. Tell us you want to achieve and maybe (but most probably) there will be a much better way to get that data in your view/template.

Comment: I am trying to integrate feefo reviews into my magento store. I know they do an extension but reading the integration guide it seems pretty straight forward, i just need to be able to include and show the 'test.php' page wherever i want the reviews to show

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `Mage::getBaseUrl` use `$root = Mage::getBaseDir();`

Comment: got it working with this `<?php require(Mage::getBaseDir().DS.'dir'.DS.'test.php');?>`

Comment: Show a full example please above

Answer (score 0):

`require('http://....')` is going to (if it's enabled) do a full-blown HTTP request to the specified URL. Since it's a URL, that webserver is going to **EXECUTE** the php script and send you its output.

If you're trying to actually load the CODE of that `test.php`, e.g. the raw un-executed PHP, then you cannot use an http request. The remote server has NO idea that the http request is actually from PHP and is coming from in include(). It'll just blindly run that script and send over the output.

You'd need to (say) rename the remote file to `test.txt`, so that the webserver sends it out as-is, and then that text will be executed as PHP code on YOUR server.

And as far as the other paths go, if your `$root` is something like:

```
 /home/sites/example.com/html
```

then the require is going to be looking for

```
 /home/sites/example.com/html/dir/test.php
```

Is there a `dir` subdir inside whatever your site's `$root` is?